# Which context/case/place can we use hexadecimal in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, hex, heidisql

refer to MySQL's official document: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

its official example:

```
mysql> SELECT X'4D7953514C', CHARSET(X'4D7953514C');
+---------------+------------------------+
| X'4D7953514C' | CHARSET(X'4D7953514C') |
+---------------+------------------------+
| MySQL         | binary                 |
+---------------+------------------------+
```

However, in my windows-MySQL5.7, I got below:  (client is Heidi )
[image]

why?

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it.

It's Heidi's problem, not MySQL's.

I changed another client (MySQL-front) , then the text result shown as "MySQL", not 0x4D79...

also I changed to print the query result in a .php page, the text result also shown corrently as "MySQL".

[image]